# Creating annotations with byte-buddy but my code can't find the annotations

Tags: java, java-8, byte-buddy

Currently I'm trying to generate my classes for my Tests via this:

```
AnnotationDescription entity = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Entity.class) //
    .build();

AnnotationDescription table = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Table.class) //
    .define("name", "FIRST_TABLE") //
    .build();

// @Column ( name = "X1", length = 20 )
AnnotationDescription nameAnnotationColumn = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Column.class) //
    .define("name", "X1") //
    .define("length", 20) //
    .build();

// @Column ( name = "X1", length = 20 )
AnnotationDescription nameAnnotationKeyColumn = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Column.class) //
    .define("name", "ADR_EXTERN_KEY") //
    .define("precision", 15) //
    .build();
Class<? extends Serializable> subclass = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Serializable.class) //
    .annotateType(entity, table) //
    .defineField("name", String.class, Visibility.PRIVATE).annotateField(nameAnnotationColumn) //
    .defineMethod("getName", String.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofField("name")) //
    .defineField("key", BigDecimal.class, Visibility.PRIVATE).annotateField(nameAnnotationKeyColumn) //
    .defineMethod("getKey", BigDecimal.class, Visibility.PUBLIC).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofField("key")) //
    .make() //
    .load(getClass().getClassLoader()) //
    .getLoaded();
```

But my own code is trying to identify a class which should have an annotation like `@Entity` and `@Table(name = "XXX")`. So the call to `.annotatypeType(..)` seemed to be either doing something I don't understand or I just create the annotations in a wrong way..

The code which tries to identify if the classes contain the `@Entity` and `@Table` annotation is in general like this:

```
public class X {
  private Class<? extends Serializable> givenClass;

  ...

if (hasAnnotation(this.givenClass.getClass().getAnnotations(), Entity.class)) {
 ....
}
```

where the method looks like this:

```
  private boolean hasAnnotation(Annotation[] annotations, Object annotationToBeExistent) {

    boolean result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i++) {
      if (annotations[i].annotationType().equals(annotationToBeExistent)) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
    return result;
```

If I create a class manually and implement is as usual the code finds the annotations...So I think my mistake must be somewhere in using byte-buddy ?

**Update**:

After thinking about it and the comment I found out that my creation was wrong it must look like this instead:

```
Serializable subclass = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class) //
    .implement(Serializable.class)
    .annotateType(entity, table) //
```

But my code will not see the created annotations?

**Update 2:**

So after your comments/suggestions (which helped a lot; Thanks for the support) I have drilled down my problem to the following code snippet: I assume my usage of AnnotationDescription or creating the annotation is not correct cause the assert will result in `false`.

```
AnnotationDescription entity = AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Entity.class) //
    .build();

Serializable subclass = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class) //
    .implement(Serializable.class)
    .annotateType(entity) //
    .make() //
    .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader()) //
    .getLoaded();
```

assertThat(subclass.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)).isTrue();

Comment: `this.givenClass.getClass().getAnnotations()` should be `this.givenClass.getAnnotations()`, no? `givenClass.getClass()` returns `Class.class`.

Comment: Unfortunately No it shouldn't cause `this.givenClass.getAnnotations()` does not exist...

Comment: Given the code you have posted, where `givenClass` *has* the type `Class`, `givenClass.getAnnotations()` should be callable and `givenClass.getClass().getAnnotations()` is wrong. Besides that, why are you creating your own implementation of `hasAnnotation` that offers no benefit over simply calling `this.givenClass.isAnnotationPresent​(Entity.class)`? Regarding [`subclass(Serializable.class)`](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.8.0/net/bytebuddy/ByteBuddy.html#subclass-java.lang.Class-): “*If the provided type is an interface, a new class implementing this interface type is created.*”

Comment: @Holger your hint make my code shorter. Thanks..And gave a thing to think about...

Comment: You are repeating the same mistake. `getLoaded()` returns the `Class`. You should invoke `.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)` on that class object. You are assigning it to a variable of type `Serializable`; that’s possible as `java.lang.Class` implements `Serializable`, but that doesn’t make it an instance of your generated class. After the assignment, you can’t invoke annotation related methods anymore, but still, it is an instance of `Class` and calling `getClass()` on it is wrong, as that will return the equivalent of `Class.class` and `java.lang.Class` surely doesn’t have your annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Your API use is correct and I could even validate the working by invoking:

```
subclass.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)
```

on your resulting class. I assume that there is a problem in your scanning logic. Some tools scan classes by introspecting class files from jars directly, maybe this is the reason that you cannot locate the class?

As for your update, are you expecting for Byte Buddy to return an instance? Byte Buddy only generates classes and `Class` types implement the `Serializable` interface which is why your code compiles to begin with:

```
AnnotationDescription entity = AnnotationDescription.Builder
    .ofType(Entity.class)
    .build();

Class<?> subclass = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class)
  .implement(Serializable.class)
  .annotateType(entity)
  .make()
  .load(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
  .getLoaded();
```

Now, the resulting class should carry your expected annotation. You can use reflection to create an instance that implements the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: First thanks for your support. See my update I have drilled down to minimal code...

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your code, see my answer.